# Bitwise operation on non flag Enum

Tags: c#

Given the following enum:

```
enum MyEnum
{
    ValueOne = 1,
    ValueEmpty,
    ValueTwo = 2,
    ValueThree = 2,
    ValueFour = ValueOne | ValueEmpty,
    ValueFive = ValueTwo | ValueThree
}
```

What are the involved operations in the ValueFour and ValueFive elements, because these are the values I get?

```
//Is assigned 3
var valueOne = (int) MyEnum.ValueFour;

//Is assigned 2
var valueTwo = (int)MyEnum.ValueFive;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ValueEmpty` is 2 (`ValueOne` +1)

`valueFour` is 3 (2 | 1) (Bitwise or, `0010` OR `0001`= `0011`)

`ValueFive` is (2 | 2) which is `2` (Bitwise or, `0010` OR `0010` = `0010`)